# Correcting fisheye distortion when camera model is known and fixed

Tags: math, geometry, computer-vision, projection, camera-calibration

I have a camera whose position is going to be fixed and we know the details of the camera. I read [here](http://www.tannerhelland.com/4743/simple-algorithm-correcting-lens-distortion/) that photoshop may hardcode the inverse transformations for different camera models and then the inverse transformations will just be a look-up table.

Can anybody guide me on how to construct that look-up table. I think that I need to have distorted and its undistorted version with me. I don't have an idea how to create that too. If I take a normal photo and a fisheye-lens photo from the exact same place, would that be correct?

Comment: The algorithm presented by the author of the article you linked *does not require a lookup table.*  It only requires two tunable parameters.

Comment: Yes, but that is a general algorithm and there are solutions to that. My question is, I know details of camera and its position too. I actually do not want a general algorithm since that will retain some distortion. I want a look-up table based method which can be near-perfect (I suppose, because I saw photoshop's quality and its very good). Regarding that article, the author writes, "the user just picks their equipment from the list, and the software applies a correction algorithm using a table of hard-coded values. "

Comment: You're still going to need the algorithm to feed the lookup table into.

Comment: Yes. Actually I am new to this, but I assume if I know the camera model and its position, I should be at some advantage. I want to know how to exploit that advantage.

Comment: I would imagine that the lookup table is simply a grid of points, and you put x and y numbers at each point corresponding to the amount and direction that you want that particular pixel to move.  The point at the center will always be 0, 0.  You would interpolate the position of the pixels in-between the grid points.

Comment: On the spot. I need to know how to get those displacement values. They should be fairly accurate than the ones obtained by general algorithm. Thats why I thought that I may need distorted and undistorted version of the same image.

Comment: Take a picture of a grid.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Even if I do that, how do I know how a undistorted grid looks like. I know this sentence sounds stupid, but what I mean is the following: If I take a chessboard image from a distance from 10 feet using a fish-eye lens. To know how it should look when flattened, do I take the chessboard pic from a distance of 10 feet with a normal camera, is it a correct procedure?

Comment: You take a picture of a grid that is the same *aspect ratio* as your camera, using a fish eye lens, so that the outer edge of the grid lines up with the outer edge of the picture.  Then you take another picture with an ordinary lens at a distance where the outer edge grid lines up with the outer edge of the picture.  Keep in mind that we still don't know Photoshop's algorithm, so all this could be wrong.

Comment: Ok. Got it. How to proceed to get the look-up table? Let me guess, choose the 4 corners of the chessboard as the correspondent points and then estimate the homography matrix. Correct?

Comment: You have to scan each photograph to find each line of dots, and compare the position of each dot with the original.  Not an easy problem, is it?  That simple algorithm that the author of the original article you linked wrote is starting to sound more attractive.  Fish eye distortion strikes me as a relatively easy problem to model with some simple math.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you observe on that link, the second image on that webpage is the input image and the distortion is too less. I have an image which has too much fish-eye distortion. Something like [this](http://www.dxo.com/sites/dump.dxo.com/files/dxoimages/photo/products/opticspro/features/optics-geometry-corrections/lens-distortion-correction/fisheye.jpg).

Comment: Yes, I know what fisheye distortion looks like.  I also *don't know* what algorithm Photoshop is using.  That's why we're having this very nice conversation in comments, and not an answer.

Comment: I showed that image not to illustrate what fish-eye distortion is, but the level of that distortion that I have to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Take two pictures of a flat surface having distinct feature points. One with as little distortion as possible, the other with fisheye distortion. For every feature point, note the undistorted (x, y) and distorted (X, Y) coordinates.

Then you will need to use some 2D interpolation scheme on irregular points. You can think of the Radial Basis Function approach or Shepard's Inverse Distance Weighting. Keep in mind that you will interpolate separately x and y seen as two functions of (X, Y).

Once you have established the interpolation, any pixel in the distorted image (having coordinates (X, Y)) will lead you to the corresponding (x, y) in the undistorted image. You will store all precomputed (x, y) in a huge LUT.

Comment: what do you mean by irregular points? Suppose, I have 100 pairs of undistorted and distorted points. The image has total (say) 256*256 pixels. Do you mean that I will need to interpolate for the 256*256-100 points to get the pixel-wise correspondence?

Comment: I mean points with arbitrary arrangement, not on a straight grid. This makes interpolation schemes much more complex and costly.

Comment: Yes you will need to interpolate for every pixel. By the way, in case you use a simple distortion model, the required LUT will have exactly the same size, storing (x, y) on every pixel, with fractional values for inter-pixel interpolation.

Comment: For speedup, you can also think of a mixed interpolation scheme, where you perform full interpolation on a coarse grid (say a node every 50 pixel) and use it to interpolate on the full resolution pixel grid by a simpler and faster scheme such as bilinear.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the horrible cost of interpolating on irregular points, I suggest you to define a simple global model such as a bivariate polynomial of low degree (say 3, having 10 DOF). You will fit the model by a least-squares approach, using the point correspondences that you have. This will be an approximation, not a true interpolation.

Classical theory uses a model built around the optical axis of the camera, somewhere close to the image center, often with circular symmetry. This results in a complex non-linear least-squares problem.

In my suggestion (polynomial), the model is less constrained and the equations remain linear.

You will not spare the evaluation of the deformation model on every pixel, even though incremental computation can spare a few cycles.

Comment: Keep in mind that the method will map the distorted image to the undistorted one. If the latter has residual distortion, this distortion will remain. So an alternative is to work with a "hand-made" undistorted image.

Comment: I have some doubts on the above and the previous answer. Suppose, I take chessboard as a test image, why will I have irregular points when I am building a model (polynomial)? I can define them to be on a straight line, right? Once I have the function, I can get the relationship as `undistorted points=f(distorted points), where f is the polynomial fit.`  2. Why should I be concerned about the computational cost? Won't the look-up table remain same as the camera position stays absolutely stable. 3. If maximum order of polynomial is 3, won't the DOF be 6, why 10? or am I understanding DOF wrong?

Comment: 1.When the picture is distorted, the point won't be on a regular grid. 2. You needn't be. 3. Why 6 ??

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues to consider for your question:

1. Building a model of the distortion, i.e. a 2-dimensional function of two variables D(x, y) = [Dx(x,y), Dy(x, y)] that maps a point on the ideal (un-distorted) image coordinate space to its distorted counterpart.
2. Use the model to warp a distorted image so to correct it.

Question 2 is easy: to quickly compute the warp you just build a warp map, i.e. a pseudocolor image whose, say, R channel encodes displacement in the X direction, and the G channel displacement along Y. Since the distortion is normally a smooth function, one need not store the warp map at full resolution. However, care must be taken in encoding the displacement with the available bits per channel, so not to lose precision - 16-bit floats (or integers encoding fixed-precision floats) are recommended. Once the warp map is known, applying it to the image is a simple matter of interpolation, as is usually performed by layer compositing tools.

Question 1 is the hard part, since the answer depends on the optical properties of the lens. If the design and materials of the lens elements are known, a closed-form model could in theory be built from first principles of geometrical optics, but in practice this is rarely done due to the complexity involved. So lens designers will normally rely on simulation by ray tracing.

In common practice, however, the details of the lens design and manufacture are not available, and the distortion must be estimated from measurements on images. Or, as you notice, you can take advantage of the work done by someone else, and consult a catalog of distortion parameter models for known lenses (or use an app that embeds such a catalog, for example [this one](http://lensfun.berlios.de/index.html)).